# How to use php session inside jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm facing with this problem : I have made a `button report` on every comment in a website to let people to report comment. I want if someone click on the button to be redirected to the popup window to let the people to login or register. I want after login/register is done this request(count) is send to database.

My problem is how can I perform this inside jQuery code :

`if(isset($_SESSION['session_user'])) { /*do something*/ }.`

Here is the code of what I already do :

```
return this.each(function (i) {
    var count = 0;
    $(this).append("<button class='" + parametres.button + " report" + i + "''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-alert'> </span>" + parametres.textBtn + "</button>").on('click', function () {
        //  if ("<%php !$_SESSION['user_session'] %>") {
        // Popup window
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        // pane register
        $('.btnReg').on('click', function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/register.php',
                data: {name: $('#nameReg').val(), email: $('#emailReg').val(), password: $('#passwordReg').val()},
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    //$('#error').fadeOut();
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-info"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer">Envoi en Cours ...</span></div>');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'exist') {
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>Ce mail n\'est pas disponible !</div>');

                    } else if (data == 'success') {
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-success"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>Inscripton effectuée !</div>');

                    } else {
                        $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>' + data + ' !</div>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        // pane login
        $('.btnLog').on('click', function (elem, i) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/login.php',
                data: {email: $('#emailLog').val(), password: $('#passwordLog').val()},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'success') {
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-info"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer">Connexion en Cours...</span></div>');
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ', 4000);
                    } else { //alert(data);
                        $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                            $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>' + data + ' !</div>');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        //}
        //This is the thing to be done after login, where to put it ?
        count = count + 1;
        if (count >= parametres.juge) {
            var content = $(this).text();
            var click = count;
            var tag = "<button class='" + parametres.button + " report" + i + "''>" + parametres.textBtn + "</button>";

            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/controller.php',
                data: {content: content,
                    click: click,
                    tag: tag},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.error) {
                        //alert(data);
                        alert('Success!');
                    }
                }
            });
            $(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
                $(this).text(parametres.textReplace).css('color', parametres.colorTex);
            }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: let me lead you to your answer - why are you using ajax in this code snippet? (hint: jquery cannot run php so it must communicate with the php on the server via ajax).

Comment: I'm using Ajax to send some datas to the login/register/controller php pages where i insert/update the database like how many times a button has been clicked. The number of click of the button reach some number like 20 the comment is automatically hide.

Comment: right right, but you wouldn't try to put the controller.php code into jquery.  in the same way, you need to use javascript to ajax a call to your php to ask if the user is logged in - then the php can use the if(isset($_SESSION['session_user'])) { do something } to send back a json_encoded message telling the javascript if the user is logged in and what to do.

Comment: juan-vargas gave a solution on how to use the session before the javascript/jquery is crafted and sent to the browser.  i have given a solution on how to put the session information you need into the dom for use later by javascript/jquery.  and you have already shown that you know how to ajax to create communication between the javascript/jquery and server side php.  those are your three options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php to determine whether or not the user is logged in, and if they are print their id into a hidden input variable.

```
<?php isset($_SESSION['session_user']): ?>
  <input type="hidden" id="session_user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['session_user_id']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in js when you need the id, you can use jquery to find it:

```
var session_user_id = $('#session_user_id').val();
```

Comment: Maybe this one could be an answer i'm making a plugin which to be used every website to let people to use it easily wihout touching code except only the call of the jquery function like this <script>$('comment_div').comment_watcher()</script>

Comment: you may need a # in front of "comment_div" if you are trying to get div with id of comment_div, unless comment_div is itself an html tag, in which case, we may not be in kansas anymore ;) good luck - it sounds cool

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this

```
if( <?php isset($_SESSION['session_user']) ?>) { do something }
```

.

Comment: yes the problem after login with the popup window i don't know how to get id of the person

Comment: i find that putting a hidden input variable in the html (printed by using php when creating the html) allows my javascript simple access to the user's id.

Comment: Does $_SESSION['session_user'] represent the user_id or username? Once a session is created you can access it on any PHP page that contains the a&lt;?php session_start();?&gt; You can just put an PHP if statement in the jQuery to check if there's a session and to whom it belongs.

Comment: it represents the user id.